# D3.js Can't Load Full CSV Dataset

Tags: csv, d3.js, file-upload

I'm currently following the tutorial in Scott Murray's D3 book.  His code for my specific problem is here: https://github.com/scotthmurray/d3-book/blob/master/chapter_07/09_time_scale.html

I copied his code into my index.html directly (for trouble shooting purposes) but it doesn't appear to be loading in my csv data correctly when I open my local host browser.

I'm trying to read in my "time_scale_data.csv" file which looks like below:

[image]

Below is I believe the relevant part of my D3 code but please see my link above for full code:
[image]

When I check my browser / console ... it looks like only the last row of data in my CSV file was loaded in instead of the whole dataset

[image]

According to the book, this is what the data should look like after I add dataset to the console:
[image]

Comment: Here is your CSV file converted to JSON: https://api.jsonbin.io/b/61cc9e42ea3bf5682139ba17

Comment: are you saying try loading again using the json file?

Comment: Yes try load as JSON, it should work

Comment: I'm getting undefined when I print the dataset in the console :( ...
I think it has to do with my rowConverter function -- probably not suited for JSON file

Comment: The code from the book was written for D3 **v4** and is not compatible with any version >=v5. You are probably using a version higher than v4 where the third argument to `d3.csv()` is now interpreted as the row conversion function. You might want to have a closer look at the API [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch#dsv) for more information. The following question may also be helpful: [*"How to load data from a CSV file in D3 v5"*](/q/49599691).